# Can we find an estimate like this: $\left|\int_0^tf\,dg\right|\le C\|f\|_{\infty}\|g\|_{\gamma}$?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, functional-inequalities, holder-spaces

Let $f\in\mathcal C^{\lambda}([0,T])$ and $g\in\mathcal C^{\gamma}([0,T])$ (i.e. they are Holder continous), where $\lambda+\gamma>1$.

Consider now the following estimate:
$$
\left|\int_0^tf\,dg\right|\le\|f\|_{\infty}\|g\|_{\gamma}t^{\gamma}+C\|f\|_{\lambda}\|g\|_{\gamma}t^{\lambda+\gamma}\;.
$$
The integral is the Young integral a generalization of the Riemann-Stiltjes integral, but don't mind about this; just consider the inequality.

Now, I saw a modification of this inequality: let $\beta\in[0,1[$ such that $\mu_{\beta}:=\gamma+\lambda(1-\beta)>1$; now $\lambda(1-\beta)\le\lambda$ thus $f\in\mathcal C^{\lambda(1-\beta)}$ and rewriting the previous inequality we have 
$$
\left|\int_0^tf\,dg\right|\le\|f\|_{\infty}\|g\|_{\gamma}t^{\gamma}+C\|f\|_{\lambda(1-\beta)}\|g\|_{\gamma}t^{\mu_{\beta}}\;,
$$
and noting that
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{\lambda(1-\beta)}
&=\sup_{0\le s<t\le T}\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|t-s|^{\lambda(1-\beta)}}\\
&=\sup_{0\le s<t\le T}\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|^{\beta}|f(t)-f(s)|^{1-\beta}}{|t-s|^{\lambda(1-\beta)}}\\
&\le2^{\beta}\|f\|_{\infty}^{\beta}\|f\|_{\lambda}^{1-\beta}
\end{align*}
the inequality reads as follows
$$
\left|\int_0^tf\,dg\right|\le\|f\|_{\infty}\|g\|_{\gamma}t^{\gamma}+C2^{\beta}\|f\|_{\infty}^{\beta}\|f\|_{\lambda(1-\beta)}^{1-\beta}\|g\|_{\gamma}t^{\mu_{\beta}}\;.
$$
The key point for me is that now, the $\sup$ norm of $f$ is taken into account in both summands, which near to what I want.

Is it possible to find a similar inequality but with $\|f\|_{\infty}$ at second summand raised exactly to $1?$

**EDIT:** The function $g$ will be a trajectory of the fractional Brownian Motion with Hurst parameter $H>1/2$; it is well known that these trajectories are $\alpha$-Holder continuous for every $\alpha<H$, but I don't know if they are also of bounded variation (I know that the trajectories of the standard BM has **not** finite bounded variation, but I don't know what about for the fBM with $H>1/2$). However this is the "only" restriction.

Comment: If an estimate like this holds, we get $\int_0^t f dg = \int f d\mu $ for all continuous $f $ and some finite measure $\mu $, by the Riesz representation theorem. This should imply $g (x) - g (y) = \mu ([x,y ]) $ for $x \leq y $ (by continuity, the boundary terms don't matter). Hence, $g $ is of bounded variation. Thus, if $g $ is Hölder continuous, but not of bounded variation, we get a function that does not satisfy what you want

Comment: It seems a good idea to insist that $g\in BV$, just to be able to make sense out of $\int f\, dg$, or at least that's what I would have thought without the OP's comment on the "Young integral."

Comment: @PhoemueX: I've edited my post! In any case thanks to both of you.